# Why is my Raspberry Pi model B overheating?

Tags: pi-b

I'm new to raspberry pi and decided to start off with the slightly older version, the model B. After plugging it in, it takes it about 5 minutes to heat up. It reaches about 60 C. It is supposed to only reach 40 C. I've already ordered some heat-sinks and a fan. What are the reasons it's heating? 
Thankyou

Comment: What sort of temperature are you talking about?  Run /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd  measure_temp

Comment: Ditto.  It is normal for the processor to be warm to the touch, ~40°C when idle.  The manufacturer has said it should not require any cooling regardless of how you use it (with the exception of overclocking).  Even maxing it out continuously, the processor will not get over ~60°C, I think.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll be the fan anyway, they're relatively cheap.

Comment: It's at 43 celcius

Comment: It's been about 10 minutes and now it's at 45 degrees.

Comment: Hi! When asking a question like this, it's useful to include what you mean by "heating up." Sometimes our preconceptions about how something should work are wrong, which I think is true in this case. The CPU and other chips are rated for environments from -20 C to +80 C. (If the environment was at +70 or +80 C, the CPU would have trouble dissipating heat, so in that case you'd want the heat-sinks and fan you've acquired. Otherwise, totally not needed, based on the specs. 

See https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=98&t=74908

Comment: Also note that CPU temperature is related to the amount of work the processor is doing. It will get slightly warmer if you are doing heavy computational work. But to confirm what others say - you do NOT need fans or heatsinks for an rPi under normal conditions, and a CPU running 40-50C is totally normal.

Comment: Okay, so in fact it is not overheating...it's at normal operating temperature.   Some people just like fans -- I think it is the white noise factor ;)

Comment: What is the ambient temperature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

43C is normal operating temp for the pi. I also have this model and when I bought my case it came with 2 aluminum stick on heat sinks mine stays about 2-3 degrees cooler with them. I also OC mine and it still operates within normal specs.